# (PHP/PDO) Separar o arquivo de Conexão com o das Funções

Tags: php, pdo

Olá, estou fazendo um sistema de login-cadastro com PDO, nunca usei pdo antes e estou aprendendo.
Minha dúvida é se é preciso separar o arquivo onde faço a conexão com o BD, das funções como cadastrarUsuário, ou deixar tudo em um arquivo só.

```
<?php 

    class Connect{
        private $pdo;
        public function __construct($db, $host, $root, $password){
            try{
                $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . $db . ";host=" . $host, $root, $password);

            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "Erro com Banco de Dados: ". $e->getMessage();
                exit();
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                echo "Erro! " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

Caso eu separe como eu iria comunicar a conexão com as funções?

Comment: Melhor em arquivo separado. Imagine que tenha varias funções ( cadastrarUsuário, atualizarUsuario, deletarUsuario etc...) em arquivos separados e que você mude algum parâmetro na sua conexão. Se sua conexão estiver no mesmo arquivo dessas funções vai ter que mudar o parâmetro em todos os arquivos dessas suas funções. No caso de estar em arquivo separado basta mudar somente nesse arquivo. Para comunicar use um include ou require. Veja como em https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php

Comment: Obrigado pela reposta Leo, mas tenho uma dúvida, após dar require no arquivo connection dentro das funções, e tentando executar a função cadastrar ele dar esse erro **Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in on line 11**, a linha é essa: `$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = :EMAIL");`
Acho que é pq n tem a variável $pdo dentro desse arquivo funções.

Comment: veja se é isso que está ocorrendo com você  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316803/erro-ao-tentar-inserir-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object

Comment: O "$this" só funciona dentro da classe que foi instanciado! Pelo jeito você está usando $this fora da classe!